# Application without tabs using ionic framework

Tags: navigation, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a application using ionic framework (am a starter to ionic framework) which has a login page and after login authentication display the profile details of the user.

When we generate app for ionic by default it is generating the app with tabs which i dont want

can any one suggest me how to create a template and initialize that template as the default state and then navigate to profile page when clicked on a button in login page using ionic framework

Thanks in Advance
Nagendra.

Comment: Means you want blank app without tabs.

Comment: absolutely correct, i need an application without tabs, which starts with a simple login screen

Comment: I think this might help you http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXqYGo?editors=101